# Keep a page the same width on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

On my page I don't use any viewport settings.
I'm just using 25% `left` and `right margin` for the whole content of the page. The problem is that when I visit it from a mobile device the width matches the width of the phone screen and with 25% margin it becomes very ugly. Just some text in the middle.

What I want to do is, make the page to does not fit the mobile screen. I want to keep it the same size. Like the most of the pages are.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what mobile device you are trying to archive?
25% left and right margin it is very relative, per sample: 25% margin in a iphone looks one way 25% margin in a tablet looks complete diferent too.

you need use **CSS3 Media Queries**

try read about
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

you can test in chrome using: Test Responsive and Device-specific Viewports

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports

I hope this can help you.